how to convert string datetime representation to datetime field in pandas?
I have a csv , with text data (sample below) .
id   |  name     |   date                     
    
123 |   abc   |  2024-08-05T21:00:26:074Z 
456 |  efg    |  2024-08-05T21:34:30.502z 

I want to filter the data based on date field , for this , i tried to read/convert datetime string to date field but get , following error => this throws an error that time data ‘2024-08-05T21:34:30.502Z" doesn’t match format “%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z” , at position ...
Question - i really don't need the time part of this date field . is there a way to ignore this and convert the rest to date field?
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df['formatted_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

filtered_df = df[df['formatted_date'] > '2024-08-05']


"is there a way to ignore this and convert the rest to date field?" - Yes. What have you tried? For example, are you aware you can use regex?

pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='mixed', errors='coerce') or pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z', exact=False) if you can have a substring.

Beside the point, but read_csv() doesn't work on this data because it doesn't have comma separators. Please provide a reproducible pandas example.

Most likely you have invalid data in your original column.

@mozway format='mixed' makes the first row NaT. %S%z doesn't match anywhere; I guess you meant to remove the %z.

@wjandrea I hadn't checked the output, I realize OP's format is ISO8601 with subseconds, since they only want the date exact=False could be used. Fair enough, I'll reopen.

Since you only need the date, you could define the format as %Y-%m-%d and use exact=False in to_datetime, this will ignore the time and solve the issue of incorrectly guessing the format:
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d', exact=False)

Output:
0   2024-08-05
1   2024-08-05
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]


This is occurring because the formats of df['formatted_date'] and '2024-08-05' are different, this can be fixed by adding this simple line: df['formatted_date'] = df['formatted_date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"). Additionally, here is the link to the documentation pandas.Series.dt.strftime - pandas 2.2.3 documentation

The error is occurring at pd.to_datetime(df['date']), not df['formatted_date'] > '2024-08-05'. Did you try this for yourself?

Oh, my bad I didn't thanks so much though.
